# SMTPServerDisconnected at /accounts/password_reset/

Tags: email, django-rest-framework, settings, sendgrid

> I tried changing my admin email from Gmail, yahoo. Mail, and now I am currently using my private email. However, I still get the same error. Now, if I use my default email address, DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, to reset the password. Everything works as it went through fine; however, no emails are in my inbox, so I can't complete the process.
> I also deleted my migrations and created new migration, but that did not work. On youtube, some coders are making a .gitinore file for their API keys and email passwords. However, I am just a practice site and keeping things easy.
> I am new to Django, so please dummies up your responses and let me know if more information is needed.
> Thanks,

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-chcaoekh$d_cl-a+mhl!*#y(!26s81pbas!wkz+u5221z3k+oj'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    "crispy_bootstrap5",
    "pages.apps.PagesConfig",
    "accounts.apps.AccountsConfig",
    "contant.apps.ContantConfig",
    "blog.apps.BlogConfig",


]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / "templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "home"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "home"

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.CustomUser"

CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "bootstrap5"
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap5"

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"  
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "support_team@derrell@.com"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "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"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "My acutal sendgrid password here"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

> Here is my django.settings I think the problem lies in here.

I tried rewriting the setting and redoing the migrations. I changed my superuser email to my private domain. However, I still get the same error. What does the error mean, and how do I fix it? Please let me know if you have the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works 100% for me , let me know if it works for you as well

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "random@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password here'
```